# brainspec/enumerize throwing mysql error for default value

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, enumeration

I'm working on a Rails 4 app, and I've begun using brainspec/enumerize gem. I have an integer value in the database, column `status` and would like to enumerate it in my model.

Below you can see the snippet I use to set it up. Unfortunately, in my tests (which were all passing previously) it complains about creating a `Partner` due to not being able to save the row. Can't assign a default status of `NULL`. Not sure where it's getting `NULL` from, as the database itself (MySQL) is set up for a default value of `0` and as you can see from below, the back-end side instructs a default of `4` or `:incomplete`.

```
enumerize :status, in: [
    :pending,    # 0 account has a pending billing request (but is not yet open)
    :active,     # 1 account has an active base subscription
    :suspended,  # 2 account has been suspended (e.g. after a base subscription decline)
    :expired,    # 3 base subscription has expired
    :incomplete, # 4 partner application process incomplete
    :closed,     # 5 account has been permanently closed
    :cancelled   # 6 account has been cancelled by user (but is still unexpired)
], default: :incomplete
```

Here is the ActiveRecord/MySQL error.

```
PartnerTest#test_create_with_nested_attributes:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'status' cannot be null: UPDATE `partner` SET `primary_contact_id` = 3, `status` = NULL WHERE `partner`.`id` = 3
    test/models/partner_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:PartnerTest>'
```

Furthermore, I know that the default value (`:incomplete`) is being picked up by Enumerize. If I throw gibberish into the default (`default: :asdoiasoas`) it baulks.

I'm using the master/branch so that it works with Rails 4.

Gemfile

```
gem 'enumerize', :github => 'brainspec/enumerize'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to brainspec/enumerize README, you should provide an integer value for each status, like:

```
enumerize :status, in: {
  pending: 0,    # 0 account has a pending billing request (but is not yet open)
  active: 1,     # 1 account has an active base subscription
  suspended: 2,  # 2 account has been suspended (e.g. after a base subscription decline)
  expired: 3,    # 3 base subscription has expired
  incomplete: 4  # 4 partner application process incomplete
                 # And so on...
}, default: :incomplete
```

As you provided only the key but not the value, it was setting it to nil/NULL.